# Why is my TomCat8 server giving me "404 Ressource not available" on one laptop but it works on my other laptop?

Tags: java, tomcat8

I'm developing a web app.

I'm trying to make it work on my new laptop.

I'm downloading the sources with git, then creating the WAR, then copying the WAR to my webapps Tomcat8 folder running on my brand new Windows 10 laptop.

The app starts very well

Then I can click on the first button, it works very fine

Then I fill the fields and when I click on "save" it doesn't work (see red message on the top of the screenshot)

[image]

When I open `dev tools`, here is what it says :

[image]

> Etat HTTP 404 - /DropMe2/api/profile-info
>
> **type** Rapport
>   d''état
>
> **message**
>   /DropMe2/api/profile-info
>
> **description** La
>   ressource demandée n''est pas disponible.Apache Tomcat/8.5.11

(sorry it's French, but it says something like "Requested resource is not available").

Which makes no sense, since on my other Windows laptop it works well and fine. I have taken the exact same sources using maven, made sure that Tomcat is restarted.

I'm having an headache on this, I have no idea where to start looking for..

Comment: What operating system are you using on the broken one? You've said that the working one is using Windows... if the other is Linux or Mac, the problem could be due to the Windows file system being case-insensitive, and Linux/Mac ones being case-sensitive...

Comment: Did you try ping or nmap on both laptops? Did you check dns works on both? Dns settings are ok on both? Are both laptops on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **configuration port for Database and Tomcat settings** ( ex: mysql, usually it is configured to **port 80**, but it might be configured to 8080 or some different ports in the other pc )

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you committed your latest changes to git? Perhaps your endpoint is out of date and the requested resource really isn't there. Tomcat also unpacks the WAR into a separate directory in webapps that doesn't get updated unless you delete it, regardless of if you uploaded a new WAR.

Answer (score 0):

So after investigating ; i had issue with Tomcat8.5 and java..

I have java7 and java8 installed both on my machine -- yes i know.
So here is what i did :

- uninstalled java 7
- uninstalled java 8
- uninstalled tomcat8.5
- reboot
- installed java 8
- installed tomcat 8.0

Well, now it works ! Yipiie !
Thanks to anyone who tried to help :)
Olivier